# The auto-complete functionality works fine but i was not able to find the id or the value that is behind actual selected item

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I have followed the below post for autocomplete functionality using angularjs in mvc, but i'm unable to get the id or the value of the selected item. Any help will be good.
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1087903/Angular-JS-AutoComplete-In-MVC-With-Web-API

Comment: selected result will be something like this-  
`{value:"rakeschand", display:"Rakeschand"}`

Comment: how to get the value: rakeschand

Comment: `self.selectedItem.value`

Comment: i'm not able to find the selected item

Comment: define in controller as `self.selectedItem = null` it's missing there

Answer (score 0):

you need to write **selectedItem** function(callback) in your controller. Its missed in [that](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1087903/Angular-JS-AutoComplete-In-MVC-With-Web-API) example.

```
self.selectedItem = selectedItem;

function selectedItem(data){
   console.log(data);  // check your selected object here
}
```

Comment: I'm not able to find the event on item selection